How to dynamically select the item based on text from hidden drop down using selenium 4 and python?(XPATH)
I have drop down option HTML code before select the drop down.
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label required-field" for="Position-GroupId">Search item</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="fs-wrap" tabindex="0"><div class="fs-label-wrap"><div class="fs-label">- Select -</div><span class="fs-arrow"></span></div><div class="fs-dropdown hidden"><div class="fs-search"><input type="search" placeholder="Search Fruit"></div><div class="fs-no-results hidden">No results found</div><div class="fs-options"><div class="fs-option selected g0" data-value="" data-index="0"><span class="fs-checkbox"><em></em></span><div class="fs-option-label">- Select -</div></div><div class="fs-option g0" data-value="22" data-index="1"><span class="fs-checkbox"><em></em></span><div class="fs-option-label">BANANA</div></div><div class="fs-option g0" data-value="84" data-index="2"><span class="fs-checkbox"><em></em></span><div class="fs-option-label">ORANGE</div>

After selecting the drop down the HTML Code as below:
Search Fruits

                                                       
                               
                               - Select -
                               No results found- Select -BANANAORANGE
I have used below code:
# 1. Wait for the dropdown to be clickable (Important!)
dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div/div[@class ='fs-label']")) # More Specific Xpath
)

# Click the dropdown to open it
dropdown.click()

Now drop down box opened.

Now I need to click ORANGE OPTION:
For that I have used below code:
# 3. Wait for the options to be visible (Important!)
orange_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/span/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'ORANGE')]"))
)

# 4. Click the "ORANGE" option
orange_option.click()

# Verification (Optional but highly recommended)
selected_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div/div"))
)
assert selected_value.text == "ORANGE", f"Expected ORANGE, but got {selected_value.text}"
print("Orange selected Successfully")

I have hard coded  the following XPATH to select each items :
//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'-Select-')]

//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/span/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'BANANA')]

//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/span/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'ORANGE')]

//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/span/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'APPLE')]

//label[contains(text(),'Fruits')]/following-sibling::div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/span/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'LEMON')]

Now how to change my hardcoded XPATH into dynamic one?
Example
Fruits = [BANANA,ORANGE,APPLE,LEMON]
random_fruits_option = random.choice(Fruits)

HTML:

While each run the fruit name should randomly select in drop down using selenium 4?

It would be better if you clarified on which element you are getting the exception.

Edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted. That error message states exactly which element is receiving the click. Once you find it on the page, you'll have a better idea of how to deal with it.

You haven't included enough HTML for us to help you. We're going to need the URL.

XPATH is just a string so you can construct it with your variable.  Something as simple as myxpath = "//div[contains(text(), '" + random_fruits_option + "')]";  should work.

Thanks It works
